# What is the precise relation between Swarm Intelligence and Ensemble Methods?

Tags: comparison, ensemble-learning, swarm-intelligence

I come from the machine learning side of AI, and have recently become more interested in the bio-inspired side of AI. Specifically I started reading about swarm intelligence and immediately started drawing analogies to ensemble methods in machine learning.

My question is: What is the precise relation between the two? Is there any reason to think of particle swarms as an ensemble of weak classifiers for example? Furthermore, can swarm intelligence methods to applied to machine learning?